# Find two nearest neigbours by geometry for a list of neighbours

Tags: sql, postgresql, geometry

I have a list of inhabitants and for every single one I need to find two nearest neighbours. So I have two tables. Schema for `inhabitants` table:

```
created_at,timestamp without time zone
updated_at,timestamp without time zone
id,integer
fist_name,character varying
last_name,character varying
home_id,integer <-- this is relation for home table
```

Schema for `home` table:

```
id, integer
humanreadiable_name,character varying
map_position,USER-DEFINED
```

`map_position` is geometry and to obtain latitude and longitude for an inhabitant I use:

```
SELECT inhabitants.id, ST_Y(ST_Centroid(ST_Transform(home.position, 4326))) AS lat,
ST_X(ST_Centroid(ST_Transform(p.position, 4326))) AS long
FROM home
INNER JOIN inhabitants ON home.id = inhabitants.home_id
WHERE inhabitants.id=1398
```

So I tried to use a semi-correct query:

```
SELECT inhabitants.id, ST_Y(ST_Centroid(ST_Transform(home.position, 4326))) AS lat,
ST_X(ST_Centroid(ST_Transform(p.position, 4326))) AS long, tmp_tab.id
FROM home
INNER JOIN inhabitants ON home.id = inhabitants.home_id
    LEFT JOIN (
SELECT inhabitants.id AS id, ST_Y(ST_Centroid(ST_Transform(home.position, 4326))) AS lat,
ST_X(ST_Centroid(ST_Transform(p.position, 4326))) AS long
FROM home
INNER JOIN inhabitants ON home.id = inhabitants.home_id
WHERE inhabitants.id=1398
        ) tmp_tab ON tmp_tab.id=inhabitants.it
WHERE (ST_Y(ST_Centroid(ST_Transform(home.position, 4326))) BETWEEN 
tmp_tab.lat-0.0005 AND tmp_tab.lat+0.0005) AND (
ST_X(ST_Centroid(ST_Transform(p.position, 4326))) BETWEEN 
tmp_tab.long-0.0005 AND tmp_tab.long+0.0005) AND inhabitants.id!=1398 
LIMIT 2
```

But it doesn't return anything.

Additionally, I'd like to pass a list of inhabitants instead of a single ID, e.g:

```
id
12
234
236
290
1209
...
278
```

And use `LIMIT 2` for all inhabitants from the list. And of course my estimation of -+0.0005 in latitude and longitude is only bacause I didn't have a better idea.

Other query which I tried is:

```
SELECT inhabitants.id AS neigbour, ST_X(ST_Centroid(ST_Transform(p.position, 4326))) AS long,
ST_Y(ST_Centroid(ST_Transform(p.position, 4326))) AS lat, '1398' AS inhabitants_from_list FROM home
    INNER JOIN inhabitants ON home.id = inhabitants.home_id
    WHERE (ST_X(ST_Centroid(ST_Transform(home.position, 4326))) BETWEEN (
        SELECT ST_X(ST_Centroid(ST_Transform(home.position, 4326))) FROM home
        INNER JOIN inhabitants ON home.id = inhabitants.home_id
        WHERE inhabitants.id=1398
             ) - 0.0005 AND (
        SELECT ST_X(ST_Centroid(ST_Transform(home.position, 4326))) FROM home
        INNER JOIN inhabitants ON home.id = inhabitants.home_id
        WHERE inhabitants.id=1398
        ) + 0.0005)
      AND 
        (ST_Y(ST_Centroid(ST_Transform(home.position, 4326))) BETWEEN (
          SELECT ST_Y(ST_Centroid(ST_Transform(home.position, 4326))) FROM home
          INNER JOIN inhabitants ON home.id = inhabitants.home_id
          WHERE inhabitants.id=1398
          ) - 0.0005 AND (
          SELECT ST_Y(ST_Centroid(ST_Transform(home.position, 4326))) FROM home
          INNER JOIN inhabitants ON home.id = inhabitants.home_id
          WHERE inhabitants.id=1398
        ) + 0.0005) AND inhabitants.id!=1398 LIMIT 2;
```

I know I should probably `ORDER BY` difference between inhabitants from the list and every single inhabitant and then `LIMIT 2`, but still the same problem persists: how to run the query for a list of inhabitants.

**Expected result is to have two nearest neighbours for each inhabitant from the list.**

Comment: What is all this stuff about centroids and x and y?  The distance operator is just `<->`, does that not work?

Answer (score 2):

You need a LATERAL join.  I don't know exactly what you need as far as columns or additional joins into "inhabitants", but the core of it would look like this:

```
select * from home a cross join lateral 
  (select * from home b where a.id<>b.id order by a.position <-> b.position limit 2) f
```